# Custom Django Template Tags not being loaded into Templates

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I have been searching the internet for quite some time for this one, but have not been able to fix my issue. I am trying to concatenate strings in one of my Django templates, and initially was using add as such...

```
{% with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/"|add:p.post_id|add:"/" as post_link %}
... used here ...
{% endwith %}
```

... but found that to be buggy and bad form. So I tried to create a custom template tag that would concatenate strings with the name addstr...

```
{% with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/"|addstr:p.post_id|addstr:"/" as post_link %}
... used here ...
{% endwith %}
```

... but am getting an "Error during Template Rendering, Invalid filter: 'addstr'" error when I do.

I created a templatetags directory in the correct spot with an **init**.py and cloud_extras.py inside of it. The contents of cloud_extras.py are:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def addstr(arg1, arg2):
    """concatenate arg1 & arg2"""
    return str(arg1) + str(arg2)
```

I also have the app properly installed in settings.py and am loading the template in the view correctly (I know this is true because I have been working with this for a while now and decided to create links for the titles of posts)

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `{% load cloud_extras %}` in the template before the call?

BTW, it looks like you probably want to look into other examples and the [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) because you probably don't want to use hardcoded links like that in the first place. Instead, try to find a way to generate the correct relative link given a post object.